# Package updater error

Tags: package-management, updates

When I start package updater I have got an error window:

> **Could not get list of distribution upgrade**
>
> Failed to process request.
>
> Spawn of helper `'/usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py'` failed:
> failed to spawn `/usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py`:
> Failed to execute child process `“/usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py”` (No such file or directory)

[image]

What is the message about and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm also getting this error message.

Comment: I'm updating from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04. I have the same message when I run GNOME Package update. (My language is not English, the actual name in your system might be different). When I run Update Manager the update succeeds.

Comment: There is a bug on Launchpad for this issue: [# 1709699](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-packagekit/+bug/1709699)

Comment: Does anyone got any solution on it. Please give here if you got any.